# Cannot find matched String in Java with an array that is created from Scanner Input

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner

After being marked as duplicate:

Ok I see that now this is a duplicate, and I apologize for a seemingly silly question. It's just from my perspective it was difficult to realise what to "search" online to solve this problem because I didn't know using `==` with strings in this manner was a problem to begin with! Even so, I'm still wondering why is using the `test` array still work in the `for` loop at the bottom of the code despite it checking with `==` and not `.equals()` but it doesn't work for the array created with stored `Scanner` input? It's because one of these methods still worked in finding `p` with `==` and not `.equals()` that made me think it was the method of storing the array that caused the problem and look in the wrong places for answers.

**Problem**:

I'm trying to make a simple AI for a problem I'm working on in Java, and part of it requires storing user input with the Java `Scanner` library in order to make an array of strings that represents a game board or "grid". I decided to store the input of this `array` "grid" one by one, asking the user to enter element for the current array position. The array is a 2-dimensional array and the input is stored one by one via two `for` loops one nested in the other as you can see near the start of the code I have provided below. I made a method called `displayGrid` that prints out the contents of 2-dimensional array in the form of a grid and it seems to take in the input correctly and the board displays correctly.

However when I try to search this "grid" after storing it with input (by using `for` loops as you can see near the end of the code snippet) the `if` statement there can't seem to verify as `true` even when I have stored the letter "p" in the first part of running the program when the Scanner is storing input into the array, and the `displayGrid` method actually prints out the array correctly showing there *is* in fact a "p" in the array. In any case, this part of the code is supposed to check if there is a "p" in the array and if there is return it's column position which I tried doing but it always returns 0 since it cannot verify that `if` statement as `true`.

The strangest thing though is that if I make a **test** array that is composed of strings as you can see at the very start of the code, and try the loop at the bottom of the code on this `test` array it *does find "p" and print it's column value*.

So are there any ideas why the loops at the bottom cannot find the "p" value of an array created from the scanner inputs near the start of the code - even when my `displayGrid` method shows that this array does contain a "p"? Thanks in advance!

Note: I haven't included rest of the code because it was largely irrelevant, but I can post it if it's really needed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // tests
    String[][] test = {{"-", "p", "-"},{"-", "-", "-"},{"-", "-", "-"}};

    // running main program
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = 0, boardSize;
    boardSize = n*n;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter n dimension of your game grid (for an nxn sized board): ");
        n = in.nextInt();
    } while(n < 3 || n > 100 || n % 2 == 0);

    String grid[][] = new String[n][n];

    System.out.println("Please enter the contents of your array now.");

    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
            System.out.print("Enter element at grid location: [" + row + "] [" + col + "]: ");
            String temp;
            temp = in.next();
            grid[row][col] = temp;
        }
    }

    // display grid for testing
    displayGrid(grid, n);

    // test
    for(int row=0; row<grid.length; row++) { 
        for(int col=0; col<grid.length; col++) { 
            if (grid[row][col] == "p") {
                System.out.println(col);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `grid[row][col] == "p"`  - This is the mistake.  See linked Question and Answers.

Comment: Ok I see that now, and I apologize for a seemingly silly questions. It's just from my perspective it was difficult to realise what to "search" online to solve this problem because I didn't know using == with strings in this manner was a problem to begin with! Also, why is using the `test` array work for that loop despite it checking with `==` and not `.equals()` but it doesn't work for the array created with stored `Scanner` input?

Comment: If your board elements are never longer than a single character, you just want a `Character` array